# A simple JS cropping function that returns data url

Tags: javascript, image

So I've tried making this function that crops skin parts for my game

```
function getSkinPart(skin, startX, startY, endX, endY){
    let skinImg = new Image();
    skinImg.src = skin
    let cropper = document.createElement("canvas")
    let cropperCTX = cropper.getContext("2d")
    cropperCTX.drawImage(
        skinImg, 
        startX,
        startY,
        endX - startX,
        endY - startY,
        0,
        0,
        endX - startX,
        endY - startY,
    )
    return cropper.toDataURL()

}
```

But it just returns a data url with a blank canvas.
I don't know what's wrong.
It's not working.

Try this example:

```js
function getSkinPart(skin, startX, startY, endX, endY){
    let skinImg = new Image();
    skinImg.src = skin
    let cropper = document.createElement("canvas")
    let cropperCTX = cropper.getContext("2d")
    cropperCTX.drawImage(
        skinImg, 
        startX,
        startY,
        endX - startX,
        endY - startY,
        0,
        0,
        endX - startX,
        endY - startY,
    )
    return cropper.toDataURL()

}

document.querySelector("#demo").href = getSkinPart("http://htmlshell.com/images/htmlshell.png", 0, 0, 50, 50)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: lightblue">
  <a id="demo">Link to new image that is cropped</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After setting the src of the image, you need to wait for the image load event. I would suggest returning a promise from your function that resolves once the image has loaded, and the selection has been made.

Comment: @Sampson could you show me an example? post your answer

Comment: Sure! I just posted something to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the logic to [use Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), which allow us to defer logic until an asynchronous task (such as loading an image) has completed. Also, be mindful of [tainted canvas elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image); you may not be able to draw if your image resources are hosted on another origin.

```js
// The image we would like to load
const url = "https://gravatar.com/avatar/a84a8714fd33f6676743f9734a824feb?s=250";

// Our getSkinPart accepts a URL, coordinates, and dimensions
const getSkinPart = (skin, x, y, width, height) => {
  // We return a promise, since we don't know how long loading the image will take
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create our canvas, context, and image element
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const skinImage = new Image();
    // Our image is remote, so we need to set the crossOrigin property
    skinImage.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    // When the image has loaded, it files the 'load' event
    skinImage.addEventListener("load", () => {
      // With the image now being loaded, we can draw it to the canvas
      context.drawImage(skinImage, x, y, width, height, x, y, width, height);
      // Next, we can resolve the promise with the dataURL
      resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
    });
    // Now that our eventListener is bound, let's set the source
    // and begin loading the image data
    skinImage.src = skin;
  })
};

// Now we call our getSkinPart method, waiting for the resolved promise
getSkinPart(url, 0, 0, 20, 20).then(dataURI => {
  // If we made it this far, add a new image to the body, and set its source
  document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement("img")
  ).src = dataURI;
});
```

Because we're using Promises, you can also use `await` if that offers a more familiar and comfortable style. Assuming we have an image element on the page already, and a button to show our preview:

```html
<img id="skinPreview" />
<button id="getSample">Get Sample</button>
```

we could do the following:

```js
// Start by gathering a couple element references
const btnGetSample = document.querySelector( "#getSample" );
const imgSkinPreview = document.querySelector( "#skinPreview" );
// Bind the click-event handler, calling an asynchronous function
btnGetSample.addEventListener( "click", async () => {
    // Gets the result from getSkinPart, and sets as image source
    imgSkinPreview.src = await getSkinPart( url, 0, 0, 20, 20 );
});
```

Comment: Hmmm doesn't work tainted canvas are the issue. Do you have a workaround

Comment: You should serve the content from an endpoint you control. If you cannot modify the responses from the server presently hosting the resources, you could stand up your own middle-man server which transmits the images with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#web_server_configuration for more information.

Comment: Hmmm is there a simpler way to crop images?

Comment: Try setting the `.crossOrigin` property on the image element as I have done in my code above.

Comment: This is too complicated is there a js library for this?

Comment: @Coder2195 No libraries will get you around security features build into the browser and web-platform. The data, if it is loaded from a remote location, could be harmful. It could be dangerous to load those bits into a canvas on the user's machine. That's why the browser refuses to do so unless precautions are taken. If your skins are hosted locally, on the same machine, you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229105/discussion-between-coder2195-and-sampson).

Comment: there wont be really any cross orgin because the only image files are through upload and built in to my game
so security shouldn't be an issue
I just need a library that crops for me

Comment: @Coder2195 If all of the resources are already loaded, then you're all set. No need to worry about cross-origin challenges. You could simply pass the image data to the function, excise a portion of it with the canvas, and return that data back to the caller.